# ASP GridView FilterExpression for All Columns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, filtering

I am displaying a gridview with several columns of data.

I want to give the user the ability to search any column of that gridview with a textbox string.

I know I can use a FilterExpression to search by a specific column, but is there a way to designate the column name with a  "*" symbol or anything representing [ALL] columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `textbox string` as a `parameter` for a `procedure` which will filter data for the `gridview.`
For example to filter employee data in gridview we can create procedure like..

```
create procedure employee_search    
    @search nvarchar(10)
as
begin
select
    e_name,e_address,e_email    
from employee
where       
    e_name like '%'+@search+'%' or 
    e_address like '%'+@search+'%' or       
    e_email like '%'+@search+'%' 
end
```

Send `textboxt string` as a `parameter` just like `@search` in the `procedure` and later bind result to `gridview.`

I am not sure whether you were looking for this answer. Hope this works for you.

Comment: yeah that makes sense.

i wasn't sure if OR was something i should use for the filter expression.

i'm manually setting the filter expression for each datasource like this:

SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = [Column] LIKE [Textbox1.Text];

But I was hoping there was an alternative to listing every column of my gridview.